# AndroidRuntime: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: local project

Tags: android, eclipse, noclassdeffounderror

I get a "AndroidRuntime: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: " exception on a class that actually exists in a local project.

**P/S:** This class is in a local Java project and not a referenced "jar" file

```
07-11 13:42:16.103: E/AndroidRuntime(647): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.cityjams.ui.Eula
```

**NOTE:**

- This exception occurs when I try to run the project
- The Eula class is in another Java project referenced by many projects
- This used to work just fine until recently

[image]

Comment: Can you give more details? When does the error occur? Is this Eula class your main activity class ?

Comment: are you using any lib's in the project..

Comment: Tried cleaning the build then re-running?

Comment: @Hbcdev tried that. Didn't work either

Comment: See if the answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10778865/android-project-unable-to-reference-other-project-in-eclipse/10778983#10778983) helps.

Comment: Yup, that was it. I had the same problem, and it's the order and export checkbox that's the trick. thanks.