# NoClassDefFoundError in android project with Java project in the build path

Tags: android, project, external, noclassdeffounderror

I am working on Android project which uses another lib project opened in Eclipse. I have noted this lib project (not a JAR file!) in the build path. All compiled good, but I received NoClassDefFoundError on execution stage. BTW, some time ago everything was fine. I think this problem after some update. What I have to do for resolving this?

Comment: [Maybe this will help](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9833655/420015)

Comment: See if the answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10778865/android-project-unable-to-reference-other-project-in-eclipse/10778983#10778983) helps.

Comment: Sorry, but I have read this articles and I have performed all recommendations, but the same situation :(

Comment: What is the type of your "lib project" exactly? Android Library Project or regular Java Project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I thing that problem is in compiler version. On the lib project compiler version must be the same as on basic android project. When I have changed this all works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Right click your project > Properties > Android: At the right side of the pop window, find Library part, click Add button to add project you want to reference.