# Include Java project as library

Tags: java, android, eclipse, cross-platform

I have three projects in my eclipse workspace:

```
EventKitchenCore
EventKitchenDesktop
EventKitchenAndroid
```

`EventKitchenCore` contains all the core functionality, and `EventKitchenDesktop` and `EventKitchenAndroid` are essentially just different user interfaces.

I have `EventKitchenCore` added and working as a library in `EventKitchenDesktop`, however I am unable to figure out how to add it as a library to `EventKitchenAndroid`.

**How do I do this?** It would be a pain in the tush to have to export as a jar in the `lib` directory every time I make a change...

I tried adding the Core project in `Properties > Java Build Path > Libraries` and `Properties > Android > Library`, but no luck :\

**Update** - for now, I got it working by exporting the core project as a jar in the libs folder. However I make frequent changes, and like I said, it's a pain in the tush.

Comment: For a pure Eclipse solution, see if the answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10778865/android-project-unable-to-reference-other-project-in-eclipse/10778983#10778983) helps.

Comment: This question is more interesting than what a quick read let me think

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Eclipse has builtin [Ant](http://ant.apache.org/) support. You can make use of it to automatically create a JAR of the current project and put it in a folder of another project.

Provided that `EventKitchenAndroid` and `EventKitchenCore` projects are both in the same workspace, create a `build.xml` file in `EventKitchenCore` project which contains just this:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project name="EventKitchenCore" default="createjar">
    <target name="createjar">
        <jar destfile="../EventKitchenAndroid/libs/EventKitchenCore.jar" basedir="bin" />
    </target>
</project>
```

To test it, select the file in Eclipse and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F11</kbd> to run it as Ant build file. If it works the way you want, then you can tell Eclipse to automatically execute this build file everytime the project is built. Go to the project properties of `EventKitchenCore` and in the *Builders* property, click *Import...* and select the `build.xml` file you just created.

Now, it will be executed everytime the project is built. You can manually force the build of a project by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd>. See also the [video demo](http://www.screencast.com/t/AXtu0ekoE0q3) I just created.

Comment: If I want to create library and it has other jar in libs, also some .dll file in ProjectNAME/libs/native/windows/xxx.dll.. Do I need to import these fill separately? Or it will be in jar/library?

Answer (score 4):

You can configure your projects as a **Maven Artifact** that depends of EventKitchenCore, so, Maven will handle this for you:

EventKitchenCore pom.xml:

```
<project ...>
   <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
   <groupId>com.adamgaskins</groupId>
   <artifactId>event-kitchen-core</artifactId>
   <packaging>jar</packaging>
   <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
   <name>EventKitchenCore</name>
</project>
```

EventKitchenDesktop pom.xml:

```
<project ...>
   <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
   <groupId>com.adamgaskins</groupId>
   <artifactId>event-kitchen-desktop</artifactId>
   <packaging>jar</packaging>
   <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
   <name>EventKitchenDesktop</name>
   <dependencies>
     <dependency>
       <groupId>com.adamgaskins</groupId>
       <artifactId>event-kitchen-core</artifactId>
       <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
     </dependency>
   <dependencies>
</project>
```

EventKitchenAndroid pom.xml:

```
<project ...>
   <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
   <groupId>com.adamgaskins</groupId>
   <artifactId>event-kitchen-android</artifactId>
   <packaging>apk</packaging> <!-- for this, you need the maven-android-plugin -->
   <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
   <name>EventKitchenAndroid</name>
   <dependencies>
     <dependency>
       <groupId>com.adamgaskins</groupId>
       <artifactId>event-kitchen-core</artifactId>
       <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
     </dependency>
   <dependencies>
</project>
```

Don't forget of SNAPSHOT suffix, otherwise, Maven will not update your changes.

Comment: More info: [link](http://www.sonatype.com/books/mvnref-book/reference/android-dev.html)

Answer (score 2):

The simplest idea (which would work outside of Eclipse, too) would be to create a symlink/shortcut from your package-directory of the library into the `src`-folder of your projects:

```
|- EventKitchenCore
   |- src/
      |- org.your.library.package <-+
|- EventKitchenDesktop              |
   |- src/                          |
      |- org/desktop/something/     |
      |- symlink to ----------------+
|- EventKitchenAndroid              |
   |- src/                          |
      |- org/android/something/     |
      |- symlink to ----------------+
```

This way, you could compile the actual projects as if your library would be a part of the applications and you have your changes immediately reflected in both your projects.

Comment: Could it be done version control and Windows friendly?

Comment: @Rekin There are symbolic links under windows, too (at least since Vista). Also, you could use [git submodules](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Tools-Submodules)

Answer (score 2):

I would say as some contributors suggest, to use maven or ant. The configuration is easy, most of them have already put them, so it is a matter of copy and paste. 
When you are in the development environment, what you can do is to add the projects in your build path. Go to build path and select the "projects" tab and add the projects you need, so every time you make changes, all the changes are visible for the projects that are linked. When you are about to deploy, you can then use the maven or ant. However, you can start with both of them in development as well. But if you want a quick fix, I would suggest to reference the projects if you don't want to use maven or ant yet. But when you deploy I strongly recommend to use one of this two project managers, because as you mentioned, export the projects as jars and then add them to the libraries folder is a pain.

Comment: -1 for repeating in an unformatted way what was already answered

Answer (score 1):

Here is a  solution that may help you :

1) Eclipse-Package Explorer - Your Project(Android) - Rightclick on your project.

2) Click on Android (At left side of screen) - Now your screen may look like this -

[image]

Now at bottom of screen, in Library section you can add all the library project directly without making any JAR. Just you need to import those library projects in workspace or all your library project should be opened in eclipse.

1) Click on Add button you will get the list of library projects available, choose from them and Build your project.

Good Luck..

Comment: Before doing this, remove all included JAR files that you have tried and also remove it from lib folder. And then try above solution.

Comment: [did you read this?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14149269/include-java-project-as-library#comment19596953_14149312)

Answer (score 0):

You have to go to the preferences of the project you want to make a library and check `Is Library` in the `Android` sub-menu. Then you can try to import your project again.

Comment: The library is a standard java library, not an android library. It has to be compatible with the desktop application.

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you are looking for is the "Link Source" option within Eclipse.  From your android project, select the project and right-click to select "Build Path" > "Link Source".  This will allow you to have your Java library accessible within the same build path as your android app for development.

Answer (score 0):

If all you want is to reference the Core projects code, then in Eclipse you can just reference this project from the Android project. (The 'library project' feature is only to Android library projects, you just have a normal Java project here, right?)

So in your Package Explorer you have all three (Core, Android and Desktop) projects. Right click `EventKitchenAndroid` and select Properties. Choose Java Build Path -> Project tab and click the Add... button. Choose `EventKitchenCore`. Go to the Order & Export tab and make sure the `EventKitchenCore` project is checked and you're good to go. Any change to the source of EventKitchenCore is immediatedly available to the Android project.

Answer (score 0):

This is the way i follow to add library to my projects

[image: Project with library]

**PHASE 1: Creating Library  Project**

Here on image you can see 2 projects named **library** and **ListSamples** which is using library

To make the project **library** as a library project right click on the project and select properties

[image: Setting Library]

Mark **IsLibrary** check box to make it library

you can see .jar file in bin folder of library project

[image: Compiled Libary]

Now the library project is created

**PHASE 2 : Adding Library Project to android Project**

Now Right click on your **android project** and select its property. then click on **Add** button inside library area and set the path of your library project to it

[image]

[image]

Then a pop- will appear showing a list of library projects you have created in eclipse which is presently active (closed library projects will not shown)

[image]

Here i got only one project so it is listed here

Select which all library you needed and click **OK**. Now the library projects will be added to your project

[image]

While checking your android project you can see the **.jar** file of your project is been added to your android project

[image]

**NOTE :-** If you are using android support package(**android-support-v4.jar**) in library project , There is no need to add it again in your Android Project .

You can also use ant to add library to projects. But i don't have knowledge about that .

Comment: You missed step 3: you add the library project to EventKitchenDesktop and watch this configuration fail

Comment: do you mean you want to add Library project inside your library and then add this combined to android project as a single library??