# Android project depends on java project

Tags: android, magento, soap, magento-1.7

I've been playing with a Java's Magento connector called magja (https://github.com/magja/magja) in a 'normal' Java project. And everything were working fine till this point.

After that, I started a simple Android application that would use the magja code to consume such information from Magento.

The question is: how should I configure the my Android project to deal with a 'normal' Java project (not a library)? This another project uses several xml files to configuration and Maven to deal with dependencies. How this impacts my Android App?

Thanks a lot!

**EDITED**

Actualy, I've already tried this approach ([Android project unable to reference other project in eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10778865/android-project-unable-to-reference-other-project-in-eclipse/10778983#10778983)), but always when the app tries to run the 'project B' (magja) code, it causes a
`java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.apache.commons.httpclient.params.HttpConnectionManagerParams`

I believe it's related to some .jar files that magja uses. It looks like that I would solve the problem if I could share such library between the projects.

Comment: I don't have experiences working with Android + Maven. But you have to make sure Magja doesn't use components which JVM supports but [Dalvik](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dalvik_(software)) doesn't.

Comment: See if the answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10778865/android-project-unable-to-reference-other-project-in-eclipse/10778983#10778983) helps.

Comment: Edited the post to share my results with the test you suggested. Tks