# Android + Scala + library project: NoClassDefFound

Tags: android, eclipse, scala, noclassdeffounderror, multiple-projects

I have a similar issue as in the SO question below, but with scala as my language of choice:

[Android project referencing "normal" java project in eclipse since sdk tools update 17](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9889572/android-project-referencing-normal-java-project-in-eclipse-since-sdk-tools-upd)

Basically, if I setup a regular android project using java,
a regular java library project and a 'glue' android library project as described in the link above, everything works fine and I can use code from my referenced regular java project.

However, if I try to repeat the same procedure using scala projects I get a noclassdeffound exception when launching. (If I move the code form the regular referenced project into the main android project the error disappears and everything works.)

Any hints on what to look for? Anyone doing the same with success?

Comment: Can you provide exact error message (what class precisely is missing)? You might forgot to include scala library on classpath.

Comment: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: xxx.yyy.ZZZ$
where ZZZ$ is a Object in scala in my lirrary project.
(If I move the xxx/yyy/ZZZ.scala from library project to main android project it works fine.)