# Ant script with eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, ant

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Want an eclipse java project to run ant build files automatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5664669/want-an-eclipse-java-project-to-run-ant-build-files-automatically)

I wonder if it´s possible to write an ant script that creates a build(jar-file) automatic every time some modicifation is done in my project(repository)? If it´s possible anyone one that can help me or link me some good pages for this.

Thank you!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5664669/want-an-eclipse-java-project-to-run-ant-build-files-automatically

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered the Ant task [uptodate](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/uptodate.html).  This allow you to compare timestamps on a set of files to another.  In your case you could compare all your src *.java files for example to your output jar.  You would then be able to have this running in a loop which would give you the desired effect.  Albeit in a fairly crude way.

This also has the benefit of not actually doing any work unless the src files have changed and can be applied to compilation as well to produce a java incremental build, that comes for "free" with other build tools.