# How to Run/Debug a Ant Project in directly in tomcat through Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, tomcat, jakarta-ee, ant

In this project ....

Web.xml is located under Project Folder > web > Web-INF > web.xml

This project is already created by or clients and we are maintaining it.

Actually we do the build using the build.xml script using ant, it will generate a app.war then we will deploy it in tomcat to run.

In the above process there is no way i can debug the code.

More info:
This is not a struts project, it is Spring MVC project

Comment: What about running the project in eclipse while developing?

Comment: i believe he is asking how to do that (running the project in eclipse) ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Want an eclipse java project to run ant build files automatically](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5664669/want-an-eclipse-java-project-to-run-ant-build-files-automatically)

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you add Ant plugin to eclipe and run it through eclipse?

Help: [How to run ant project in eclipse](http://help.eclipse.org/neon/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.user%2Ftasks%2Ftasks-ant-running.htm)

**Running Ant buildfiles**

To run an Ant buildfile in the Workbench:

1. In one of the navigation views, select an XML file.
2. From the file's pop-up menu, select Run Ant.... The launch
   configuration dialog
       opens.
3. Select one or more targets from the Targets tab. The order in
       which you select the items is the order in which they will run. The
       order is displayed in the Target execution order box at the bottom
       of the tab. You can change the order of the targets by clicking the
       Order... button.
4. (Optional) Configure options on the other tabs. For
       example, on the Main tab, type any required arguments in the
       Arguments field.
5. Click Run.

or Check this answer

[Want an eclipse java project to run ant build files automatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5664669/want-an-eclipse-java-project-to-run-ant-build-files-automatically)