# Eclipse runs ANT twice, even sending run only once

Tags: java, eclipse, ant, jar

In Netbeans, after some research, I managed to edit the file build.xml to customize the way the IDE generated my jar and my manifest file. I had to migrate a project for Eclipse, and even found the option to build jar, but I need to build my jar with some personalized information.

I added the file build.xml as a buildfile ANT in my project in eclipse, but when I send execute it, the eclipse runs twice, generating 2 jars files at once.

Follow my file build.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<project name="GerOficios" default="makejar" basedir='.'>

    <target name="makejar">

        <property file="version_info.properties" />

        <property name="application.title" value="GerOficios_v6" />

        <property name="main.class" value="com/dfmachado/geroficios/View/ListaDeOficiosUI" />

        <buildnumber file="build.num" />

        <property name="build.version.num" value="${version.number}.${build.number}" />

        <tstamp>
            <format property="TODAY" pattern="dd/MM/yyyy - HH:mm:ss" />
        </tstamp>

        <property name="store.jar.name" value="GerOficios ${build.version.num}" />

        <property name="store.dir" value="store" />
        <property name="store.jar" value="${store.dir}/${store.jar.name}.jar" />

        <echo message="Packaging ${application.title} into a single JAR at ${store.jar}" />

        <mkdir dir="${store.dir}" />

        <jar destfile="${store.dir}/temp_final.jar" basedir="bin" filesetmanifest="skip">
            <zipgroupfileset dir="lib" includes="*.jar" />

            <manifest>
                <attribute name="Main-Class" value="${main.class}" />
                <attribute name="SplashScreen-Image" value="com/dfmachado/geroficios/View/image/minerva.png" />

                <attribute name="Build-OS" value="${os.name} version ${os.version} on ${os.arch}" />
                <attribute name="Java-Version" value="${javac.source}" />
                <attribute name="Implementation-Title" value="${application.title}" />
                <attribute name="Implementation-Version" value="${build.version.num}" />
                <attribute name="Built-By" value="${user.name}" />
                <attribute name="Built-Date" value="${TODAY}" />
            </manifest>
        </jar>

        <zip destfile="${store.jar}">
            <zipfileset src="${store.dir}/temp_final.jar" excludes="META-INF/*.SF, META-INF/*.DSA, META-INF/*.RSA" />
        </zip>
        <delete file="${store.dir}/temp_final.jar" />

    </target>

</project>
```

Just to point out, the eclipse generates a jar the way it generated in netbeans, the problem is the ANT run twice and generate 2 jars, even I giving command only once, as can be seen in print below:

[image]

Running the ant via the command line in the same project and only one file was created, apparently the problem is some configuration in eclipse, but I have not been able to find any so far.

Comment: Top of my head, there's just one thing can cause this. ANT is a builder you've added in the project builders. (Project -> Right Click -> Properties -> Builders)

Comment: @alok Amazing! Was exactly this. Thank you for support, I no longer knew where to look. :)

Comment: @alok So I don't need to add in "Builders" if it is to generate the jar just manually?

Comment: If the workspace is set to build automatically, then yes!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ANT is a builder you've added in the project builders. Please check it here:

> Project -> Right Click -> Properties -> Builders

You can keep it enabled in conjunction with Eclipse's workspace set to "build automatically" - this will trigger automatic builds.

Or, you can deselect the builder from the builders list and run it manually whenever needed!

[This SO Q+A is worth a quick (further) read](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5664669/want-an-eclipse-java-project-to-run-ant-build-files-automatically)