# JBAS014613: Operation ("deploy") failed - address: ([("deployment" => "test.war")])

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, wildfly-8

Getting server log error - **earlier**

```
13:31:25,905 INFO  [org.jboss.as.jpa] (MSC service thread 1-3) JBAS011401: Read persistence.xml for testJpaUnit
13:31:27,731 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (Controller Boot Thread) JBAS014613: Operation ("deploy") failed - address: ([("deployment" => "test.war")]) - failure description: {"JBAS014771: Services with missing/unavailable dependencies" => ["jboss.persistenceunit.\"test.war#testJpaUnit\".__FIRST_PHASE__ is missing [jboss.naming.context.java.testDataSource]"]}
```

**update after changes**
You will come across `deployment.internal.ear`, which is another package needed for this app to work and is getting deployed properly.

```
11:30:08,028 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources] (MSC service thread 1-1) JBAS010400: Bound data source [java:/testDataSource]
11:30:31,216 INFO  [org.jboss.as.jpa] (MSC service thread 1-6) JBAS011401: Read persistence.xml for testJpaUnit
11:30:33,921 INFO  [org.jboss.as.jpa] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 50) JBAS011409: Starting Persistence Unit (phase 1 of 2) Service 'test.war#testJpaUnit'
11:30:33,966 INFO  [org.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 50) HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [
    name: testJpaUnit
    ...]
11:30:34,313 INFO  [org.hibernate.Version] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 50) HHH000412: Hibernate Core {4.3.7.Final}
11:30:34,314 INFO  [org.hibernate.cfg.Environment] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 50) HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
11:30:34,318 INFO  [org.hibernate.cfg.Environment] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 50) HHH000021: Bytecode provider name : javassist
11:30:54,858 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-1) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.deployment.unit."test.war".POST_MODULE: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit."test.war".POST_MODULE: JBAS018733: Failed to process phase POST_MODULE of deployment "test.war"
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:166) [wildfly-server-8.2.0.Final.jar:8.2.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1948) [jboss-msc-1.2.2.Final.jar:1.2.2.Final]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1881) [jboss-msc-1.2.2.Final.jar:1.2.2.Final]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.8.0_144]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.8.0_144]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.8.0_144]
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: JBAS018757: Error getting reflective information for class com.service.ServiceBeanImpl with ClassLoader ModuleClassLoader for Module "deployment.internal.ear:main" from Service Module Loader
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.reflect.DeploymentReflectionIndex.getClassIndex(DeploymentReflectionIndex.java:72) [wildfly-server-8.2.0.Final.jar:8.2.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.ee.metadata.MethodAnnotationAggregator.runtimeAnnotationInformation(MethodAnnotationAggregator.java:58)
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.deployers.InterceptorAnnotationProcessor.handleAnnotations(InterceptorAnnotationProcessor.java:107)
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.deployers.InterceptorAnnotationProcessor.processComponentConfig(InterceptorAnnotationProcessor.java:92)
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.deployers.InterceptorAnnotationProcessor.deploy(InterceptorAnnotationProcessor.java:77)
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:159) [wildfly-server-8.2.0.Final.jar:8.2.0.Final]
    ... 5 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hibernate/StatelessSession
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.8.0_144]
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.8.0_144]
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.8.0_144]
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.reflect.ClassReflectionIndex.<init>(ClassReflectionIndex.java:65) [wildfly-server-8.2.0.Final.jar:8.2.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.reflect.DeploymentReflectionIndex.getClassIndex(DeploymentReflectionIndex.java:68) [wildfly-server-8.2.0.Final.jar:8.2.0.Final]
    ... 10 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.hibernate.StatelessSession from [Module "deployment.internal.ear:main" from Service Module Loader]
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:213) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.3.Final]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:459) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.3.Final]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassChecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:408) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.3.Final]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:389) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.3.Final]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:134) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.3.Final]
    ... 15 more

11:30:54,904 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (Controller Boot Thread) JBAS014613: Operation ("deploy") failed - address: ([("deployment" => "test.war")]) - failure description: {"JBAS014671: Failed services" => {"jboss.deployment.unit.\"test.war\".POST_MODULE" => "org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit.\"test.war\".POST_MODULE: JBAS018733: Failed to process phase POST_MODULE of deployment \"test.war\"
    Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: JBAS018757: Error getting reflective information for class com.service.ServiceBeanImpl with ClassLoader ModuleClassLoader for Module \"deployment.internal.ear:main\" from Service Module Loader
    Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hibernate/StatelessSession
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.hibernate.StatelessSession from [Module \"deployment.internal.ear:main\" from Service Module Loader]"}}
11:30:55,022 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 28) JBAS018559: Deployed "test.war" (runtime-name : "test.war")
11:30:55,022 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 28) JBAS018559: Deployed "internal.ear" (runtime-name : "internal.ear")
11:30:55,027 INFO  [org.jboss.as.controller] (Controller Boot Thread) JBAS014774: Service status report
JBAS014777:   Services which failed to start:      service jboss.deployment.unit."test.war".POST_MODULE: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit."test.war".POST_MODULE: JBAS018733: Failed to process phase POST_MODULE of deployment "test.war"

11:30:55,239 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) JBAS015961: Http management interface listening on http://127.0.0.1:9990/management
11:30:55,239 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) JBAS015951: Admin console listening on http://127.0.0.1:9990
11:30:55,239 ERROR [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) JBAS015875: WildFly 8.2.0.Final "Tweek" started (with errors) in 609354ms - Started 237 of 294 services (1 services failed or missing dependencies, 92 services are lazy, passive or on-demand)
11:30:56,582 INFO  [org.jboss.as.jpa] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 2) JBAS011410: Stopping Persistence Unit (phase 1 of 2) Service 'test.war#testJpaUnit'
11:31:03,510 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-3) JBAS015877: Stopped deployment test.war (runtime-name: test.war) in 6930ms
11:31:03,715 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 2) JBAS018558: Undeployed "test.war" (runtime-name: "test.war")
11:31:03,716 INFO  [org.jboss.as.controller] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 2) JBAS014774: Service status report
JBAS014777:   Services which failed to start:      service jboss.deployment.unit."test.war".POST_MODULE
```

I have tried changing hibernate entitymanager jar from 4.2 -> 4.3 and searched stackoverflow similar answers and jboss documentations. But not helped.

`persistence.xml` - **updated**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence
      http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd"
    version="2.0">

    <!-- A JPA Persistence Unit -->
    <persistence-unit name="testJpaUnit">
        <provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>

        <non-jta-data-source>java:/testDataSource</non-jta-data-source>

        <!-- JPA entities must be registered here -->
        <class>com.test.DemoClass</class>
        <class>com.test.DummyClass</class>
        <properties>
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect" />
            <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="none"/>
            <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="false" />
        </properties>

    </persistence-unit>

</persistence>
```

Please help so that I can deploy the web app to the wildfly server.

**Update**
`changes to standalone.xml`

```
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:datasources:2.0">
            <datasources>
                <datasource jndi-name="java:jboss/datasources/ExampleDS" pool-name="ExampleDS" enabled="true" use-java-context="true">
                    <connection-url>jdbc:h2:mem:test;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE</connection-url>
                    <driver>h2</driver>
                    <security>
                        <user-name>sa</user-name>
                        <password>sa</password>
                    </security>
                </datasource>
                <datasource jta="false" jndi-name="java:/testDataSource" pool-name="testDataSource" enabled="true" use-java-context="true">
                    <connection-url>jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test</connection-url>
                    <driver>com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</driver>
                    <security>
                        <user-name>root</user-name>
                        <password>root</password>
                    </security>
                </datasource>
                <drivers>
                    <driver name="h2" module="com.h2database.h2">
                        <xa-datasource-class>org.h2.jdbcx.JdbcDataSource</xa-datasource-class>
                    </driver>
                </drivers>
            </datasources>
        </subsystem>
```

**PS** I haven't share logs which is irrelevant and and some name of Classes is changed due IP. like `com.service.ServiceBeanImpl`

Comment: can you share database configuration from wildfly server?

Comment: are you talking about standalone.xml file?

Comment: Yes if you are using standalone mode.

Comment: Are you using standalone mode? Or Domain mode to start the server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used Ant+ivy build method to solve the issue. There was directory structure issue in the war created by Wildlfly. Do follow comments above to understand this issue more and solution stages.

Also, Do follow above given link if you want to setup automatic build in eclipse for ant.

Thank you Abhijeet.

Answer (score 0):

According to the database configuration shared by you from `standalone.xml`, You don't have datasource named `testDataSource` created on your wildfly server. Create non-jta datasource on your wildfly server with name as `testDataSource`. Once you create datasource you will be able to deploy your application.

Comment: I had to add ```java:/testDataSource``` which is not accepted by application and changing in persistence.xml to ```java:/testDataSource```. break some other part of application throwing error like ClassNotFoundException for stateless

Comment: can you share whole stack trace? share updated configuration as well

Comment: Ok I will do it later today. Thanks you for help till now.

Comment: np. Just let me know if you face any issue

Comment: I have updated the question with latest logs and configurations. I had to change some class name due to IP.

Comment: Hey @user8215559, you need to add MySQL Driver first in your jboss then you can use it. According to your configuration, you only have "h2" DB drivers

Comment: First, add MySQL driver then add datasource using this driver

Comment: @Sumit Are you able to install MySQL driver?

Comment: I'm sorry for late reply. Actually, war from production is getting deployed and ran with default standalone.xml configuration. I want to ask you. Does directory structure inside war affects in war deployment. If yes, how can we make wildly or eclipse to build war using build.xml file inside project. Thank you Abhijeet for your help.

Comment: @SumitRanjan Yes. Directory structure inside war affects deployment. Wildfly does not build the war and to build project through eclipse you can refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5664669/want-an-eclipse-java-project-to-run-ant-build-files-automatically

Comment: Thank you @Abhijeet. I will update once I get it solved.